Recurring keyboard debounce(?) issue - missing keystrokes
I have a Dell Precision 5510 (identical to the XPS 9550) running Windows 10, and in the last few days, there have been 3 mornings that the computer "woke up" with a frustrating keyboard issue: the keyboard doesn't "lag," but it does miss keystrokes. For example, if I press any key 6 times fast, only 3 strokes are registered. Or if I type text at normal speed, it comes out like this: tex typed at norml sped. If I type slowly, everything comes through fine.
The issue persists when I restart in safe mode, or even when I reboot to BIOS. But eventually I have gotten the keyboard to work after shutting down the computer and leaving it off and unplugged for a few minutes. (Except that didn't work today--yet!) Then it's fine for a couple of days before going back to the same issue.
Unfortunately I don't have an external keyboard to try at this time. The on-screen keyboard does NOT exhibit the same problem, so between that and the BIOS it seems like it could hardware-related. I've tried re-seating the ribbon cables, except for one I can't access without taking out the mother-board. Any tips for anything else to try, or is the only option to change out hardware?
FYI, I also periodically have a problem where both CTRL keys become unresponsive for a time--they wake up after hitting them several times. Just mentioning that in case it could be related, though it doesn't show up at the same moments.

It sounds as though you already know what you need to try: an external keyboard. These are either very cheap, or you could borrow one from a friend or neighbor. If your keyboard is exhibiting these behaviors outside any OS you need to try a different keyboard.

For one laptop with a similar issue, I had to change the keyboard. What caused it was something pressing on the keys when closed.

FYI, an external keyboard functions correctly with no issues, so I'm afraid the keyboard hardware itself is likely malfunctioning, but the laptop is old enough that it makes more sense to use an external keyboard rather than replacing the internal one.
